# How to change formatting of value on mouse hover using interactive mode

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph, shown here, in matplotlib. On hover, it shows the coordinates of the point in the top right corner, as well as the value underneath it. However, I'm trying to change the value portion to not be in scientific notation, but have it display as it's full integer (or any formatting).

[image: image of scientific notation on matplotlib]

I am using `format_coordinates` from this section here to format the coordinates, so I thought that it would also be in that section. However, I couldn't find something to pass into to format the value itself. Here's the code responsible for making the coordinates on hover snap to the nearest integer:

```
def format_coordinates_int(self,x,y) :
      return "X=%i Y=%i" % (int(x+0.5), int(y+0.5))

axes.format_coord = self.format_coordinates_int
```

What should I pass this formatting into to have the same effect on the value?

Answer (score 1):

In order to format as an integer the value displayed on hover, you should use the **ScalarFormatter** class from matplotlib.ticker module.
It automatically determines the format of the tick labels based on the range of values.
By default, **ScalarFormatter** uses the scientific notation for large or small values...however, setting "useOffset=False" and "useMathText=False", we can obtain plain integer formatting.
The *format_data* method returns a string representation of it.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def format_coordinates_int(self, x, y):
    x_int = int(x + 0.5)
    y_int = int(y + 0.5)
    value = self.norm(x, y) # value of the point, normalizing the data to the range [0, 1]
    value_int = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False, useMathText=False).format_data(value) 
    return f"X={x_int} Y={y_int} Value={value_int}"

axes.format_coord = self.format_coordinates_int
```

Comment: I'm confused on `value = self.norm(x,y)` Is this psuedo code for getting the value itself?

Comment: I was more asking about the `norm()` function. Where did this come from?